# How to set a timeout for recvfrom in socket Python

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, udp

I have a neat little program here that just connects to servers. It is a UDP client. It is supposed to send a message to the server and wait for the response.

```
import socket

host = socket.gethostname() # Change to the ip address 
port  = 4000

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
message = input('Send_To_Server: ')

while message != 'endhost':
     s.sendto(message.encode('utf-8'), (host, port))
     data, addr = s.recvfrom(1024)
     data = data.decode('utf-8')
     print("Received from server: " + data)
     message = input('Send_To_Server: ')
s.close()
```

The only problem is that if the server is not up, it just sits there. Is there any way to set a timeout so after so many seconds it goes over the command?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set timeout on python's socket recv method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2719017/how-to-set-timeout-on-pythons-socket-recv-method), [python udp client time out machinsm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18311338/python-udp-client-time-out-machinsm), [Handling a timeout error in python sockets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11865685/handling-a-timeout-error-in-python-sockets)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `settimeout` function :

```
import socket

host = socket.gethostname() # Change to the ip address 
port  = 4000

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.settimeout(10)
message = input('Send_To_Server: ')

while message != 'endhost':
     s.sendto(message.encode('utf-8'), (host, port))
     data, addr = s.recvfrom(1024)
     data = data.decode('utf-8')
     print("Received from server: " + data)
     message = input('Send_To_Server: ')
s.close()
```

This will set a 10s timeout.